# Clojure koans 14 - converting a map to a string

Tags: strings, clojure

The koan is at the end of this snippet. It requires you to write a function to convert a map to a string, and then prepend a full name to it.

The following solution works fine. I am just wondering if there are simpler or more efficient ways of doing the same thing.

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Solution
(defn str-addr [addr]
  "Turn a map of address into a string in the format of STREET, CITY, STATE"
  (let [{:keys [street-address city state]} addr]
    (str street-address ", " city ", " state)
    )
  )
(defn prefix-name-to-addr [[fn ln] addr]
  "Prepend names to an address."
  (let [
        name-string (str fn " " ln)
        addr-string (str-addr addr)
        ]
    (str name-string ", " addr-string)
    )
  )
; (prefix-name-to-addr ["Victoria" "Leong"] test-address)
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

(def test-address
  {:street-address "123 Test Lane"
   :city "Testerville"
   :state "TX"})

"All together now! Fill in a function to make the follow expression eval to true."
(= "Test Testerson, 123 Test Lane, Testerville, TX"
   (prefix-name-to-addr ["Test" "Testerson"] test-address))
```

Answer (score 2):

Performance is not an issue here - there is just not enough to do to
make that a concern.  This review is also overkill for the same reason,
so I'll talk about what should be changed should you want to use this
code in the context of a larger program than about just 20 lines.  *And*
my naming suggestions may not be idiomatic Clojure, I wouldn't know.

So, for style, the first thing to note is that parentheses shouldn't be
on their own like this.  If your editor makes it difficult, get one
which will automatically keep the structure correct and indents
properly.

Next, the docstring to `str-addr` is missing a full stop and the single
string (`"All together now! .."`) is above 80 characters per line.

I don't like abbreviations.  `addr` is a bit shorter than `address`, but
really, `str-addr` is not the easiest to decipher.

Now what that function does, is not really turning an address into a
string (not a map of an address, an address in this program is
implicitely defined to be a map with (at least) the three fields
`street-address`, `city`, `state`, so treat it like a data type), but
rather formatting it for human display.  So better names would be
`format-address`, `print(able)-address`, `readable-address`, or so.

Instead of the destructuring, you can use `map` or even `juxt` to
directly extract the fields.  That saves another line in that function
at the cost of using keywords to specify the fields.

Then, use `join` from `clojure.string` to join strings with a separator,
much cleaner if you have more parameters.  If you have a more complex
format, use `format`.

`prefix-name-to-address` could suggest that it is turning a
`prefix-name` into an address - I'd probably use a different name
altogether.  What it does is formatting a full address line, so
something like `format-full-address`.  Also, your name data type, a
vector, is very limited here.  At least by not restricting the number of
names a person can have, you get more flexible and at the same time
smaller code.

So, if I combine these suggestions into code, it would look like the
following:

```
(use 'clojure.string)

(defn format-address [address]
  "Turn an address into a string in the format of 'STREET, CITY, STATE'."
  (join ", " (map address [:street-address :city :state])))

(defn format-name [name]
  "Turn a name (a sequence of first name to last name) into a string."
  (join " " names))

(defn format-full-address [name address]
  "Prepend a name to an address."
  (join ", " [(format-name name) (format-address address)]))

(def test-address
  {:street-address "123 Test Lane"
   :city "Testerville"
   :state "TX"})

;; All together now! Fill in a function to make the follow expression eval to true.
(= "Test Testerson, 123 Test Lane, Testerville, TX"
   (format-full-address ["Test" "Testerson"] test-address))
```